# check if input is within specified ranges in c++

Tags: c++, position, range

I'm asking for inputs and I want to have outputs depending on the range within the inputs fall.

**example**:

- I accept inputs like 0.3 0.55 etc.
- Range is 0.0 to 1.
- The "step" is 0.1. Meaning there are 10 positions/checkpoints.
- If the input is 0.3, since it is three times the "step" it should return "position 3", if it is smaller than 0.3 but larger than 0.2 it should return "between positions 2 and 3" etc.

**question:**

- Can this be done without explicit if-statements, or switch cases, for all possible positions??

Comment: Yes, but you need to concern the usual [floating point number things](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: I'm assuming there are no abnormal inputs or inputs with higher precision than 3 digits

Comment: use loop to compare inputs with your steps.

Comment: wouldn't there be a need for if-statements inside the loop?

Comment: @user3374479: Well, there's at least one place where you need to check a condition. However, every `if` can be replaced by a `for`, and in this case one can just use the loop for the check.

Comment: @user3374479, no, if you'll use while loop.

Comment: @user3374479, I was wrong, the answer given below is correct, at least one `if` statement needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to write such a function, based on the value of (input-range_min)/(range_max-range_min)*10.

```
struct Position
{
    int positionLow;
    bool inBetween;
};

Position WhereInRange(float input, float minScale, float maxScale, int numPositions)
{
    Position res;
    float fPlace = (input-minScale)/(maxScale-minScale)*numPositions;
    res.positionLow = int(floor(fPlace));
    res.inBetween = res.positionLow != fPlace;
```

}

Comment: Could you please elaborate in a quick example? Thanks!